# Most apps crashes on Android emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, mobile, amd-processor

I'm running android emulator with a virtual device API version 21 (also same testing on 22) because apparently my processor, AMD Phenon II x6 1055t, is not supported by google anymore as I have researched here on SO. Indeed creating a device with version 21 or 22 successfully made the emulator open and boot the virtual device OS.

Now my problem is that the app I'm developing does not open, it either crashes or freeze during load.

This is not unique to the app I'm developing, maps, settings, and the sample project from android studio also do not open. For maps and settings I see the message that google play services stopped working.
BTW if I reboot the device, this message that google play services stopped working floods with popups for about 2 minutes until it stops after that time.

I have captured the error messages by running the emulator with this command:

```
emulator @Pixel2_21 -logcat '*:v'
```

and pasted the complete log here.

I can provide more logs if someone instructs me on how to do so.

I wonder if shows any clues or if I'm still at a stage that it could be anything.

**Update 1.**
By selecting another image that does not include google API I was able to launch some of the native apps that were not loading before. Same API version 21, just selected another one that do not include the google API.
The app I'm developing still does not load though

**Update 2**
See the link below for more info on specific compatibility for my processor related to the Android OS API versions:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37076174

Comment: I could not format the link correctly

Comment: My guess is that the version of Android that you are running on the emulator does not support the SDK that you are compiling against nor of the applications you are trying to run. Or perhaps the apps are compiled expecting CPU instructions that are not provided by your CPU. Why is your CPU no longer supported by Google?

Comment: @RichardChambers I have been trying to make this work for a while now and read many SO questions and answers, one of the answers had a link to a documentation from google saying that there was something in the OS images that would not support that kind of proccessor anymore since it lacked some feature, so I downgraded the image to 22 and for the first time the emulator was able to make the virtual device boot. But then the app does not load.
Also updated my question with a new test I have done

Comment: Before you run your app type "fatal" in your Logcat's regex area (That is for filtering logs and show only fatal error logs). 

Then run the app and see it crash. 
Then you will see red text in Logcat area.

 If you post that here, it would be easier to figure out why your app crashes.

Comment: Thanks @TahirFerli will do so

Comment: Updated the description adding a link where other users mention having a problem related to the same CPU type that I have with the different Android versions